# Cant click on the right click menu during automation as it is outside the DOM

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-14

I'm trying to automate a test for which I need to search a movie, right-click on a link and select the first option (open in new tab).
Have tried initiating a robot class, using the action class, treating the right-click selection window as a separate window, and even sending a "shift+enter" command after selecting the link. None of it worked.
the most popular solution (the action class) had the problem that even though I was able to right-click the link by, using a context-click when I gave the command to "press the down key of the keyboard" instead of moving into the right-click menu, it scrolled by webpage down, i.e. it did not interact with the menu at all. Although when I manually click the down button, it obviously selects the first option of the menu. (Have tried multiple Keys.DOWN commands as well)
Here's my action class code:

```
 driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    search.click();
    search.sendKeys("After life"+ ENTER);
    WebElement toClick =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'After Life (TV Series 2019–2022) - IMDb')]"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.contextClick(toClick).perform();

    actions.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(ENTER).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is makes sense to get "href" attribute, open a tab manually and go to the link on the new tab?

Comment: actually, the goal is to press that option, so there isn't any other way around it sadly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is not working with `Actions` class and I assumed you are using `Keys.DOWN` instead of `keys.ARROW_DOWN`. Even it is also not working with `keys.ARROW_DOWN`. By using both `Actions` and `Robot` classes it worked.

**Code**:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.contextClick(toClick).perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: It still isn't working on my side.
the only thing i have to add here is that the function im calling my method in requires 

"hrows InterruptedException, AWTException "

these exception handlers.
The robot is doing something, as the right-click menu closes once the robot actions are called and i get a beep on my mac, but other than that NO LUCK!
could java and selenium versions have anything to do with it?

Comment: I think the beep might be cause the robot is trying to press the down button on a screen where pressing the down button wont do anything
that when i usually hear that beep 
anyways if you can help me out further (youve already tried alot and i really appreciate it) i'll appreciate it even more!

Comment: Are you using keyRelease after KeyPress?

Comment: Yes, I tried running the same code you wrote above, but to no avail.
the robot keeps interacting with the webpage behind the edit menu, which basically means that when I tell it to press the down button on my keyboard through the robot code, instead of interacting with the edit menu, it scrolls down the webpage